# Compare values in a grouped data frame with corresponding value in a vector

Tags: r

Let's  say I got a data.frame like the following:

```
u <- as.numeric(rep(rep(1:5,3)))
w <- as.factor(c(rep("a",5), rep("b",5), rep("c",5)))
q <- data.frame(w,u)

q

  w u
1  a 1
2  a 2
3  a 3
4  a 4
5  a 5
6  b 1
7  b 2
8  b 3
9  b 4
10 b 5
11 c 1
12 c 2
13 c 3
14 c 4
15 c 5
```

and the vector:

```
v <- c(2,3,1)
```

Now I want to find the first row in the respective group [i] where the value [i] from vector "v" is bigger than the value in column "u".

The result should look like this:

```
1 a 3
2 b 4
3 c 2
```

I tried:

```
fun <- function (m) {
  first(which(m[,2]>v))
}

ddply(q, .(w), summarise, fun(q))

and got as a result: 

  w fun(q)
1 a      3
2 b      3
3 c      3
```

Thus it seems like, ddply is only taking the first value from the vector "v".

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: The `ddply` is returning single value because you are applying the full column `m[,2]` i.e. `q[,2]` along with the fact that `v` is the full vector and not corresponding element for each group

Answer (score 1):

We can join the `vector` by creating a data.frame with 'w' as the `unique` values from 'w' column of 'q', then do a `group_by` 'w' and get the first row index where u is greater than the corresponding 'vector' column value

```
library(dplyr)
q %>% 
   left_join(data.frame(w = unique(q$w), new = v)) %>%
   group_by(w) %>% 
   summarise(n = which(u > new)[1]) 
   # // or use findInterval
   #summarise(n = findInterval(new[1], u)+1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  w         n
#* <fct> <int>
#1 a         3
#2 b         4
#3 c         2
```

---

or use `Map` after `split`ting the data by 'w' column

```
Map(function(x, y) which(x$u > y)[1], split(q,q$w), v)
#$a
#[1] 3

#$b
#[1] 4

#$c
#[1] 2
```

---

OP mentioned that comparison starts from the beginning and it is not correct because we have a `group_by` operation.  If we create a column of sequence, it resets at each group

```
q %>% 
    left_join(data.frame(w = unique(q$w), new = v)) %>%
    group_by(w) %>% 
 mutate(rn = row_number())
Joining, by = "w"
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   w [3]
   w         u   new    rn
   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1 a         1     2     1
 2 a         2     2     2
 3 a         3     2     3
 4 a         4     2     4
 5 a         5     2     5
 6 b         1     3     1
 7 b         2     3     2
 8 b         3     3     3
 9 b         4     3     4
10 b         5     3     5
11 c         1     1     1
12 c         2     1     2
13 c         3     1     3
14 c         4     1     4
15 c         5     1     5
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't work (although it gets a supposedly right result. This code also starts looking from the start for u > new. However, for the second value, it should start from the first value of group b.

Comment: @RaphaelKnecht Have you noticed that I used `group_by(w)`.  So, it is doing the comparison in the correct way i.e. resetting the row_number() for each grouping

Comment: @RaphaelKnecht you can check the `rn` I created.  It resets at each group

Comment: @RaphaelKnecht if you can provide a specific use case of this failing, it would be great

Comment: sorry, my bad. It works now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`: for each 'w' (`by = w`), subset 'v' with the group index `.GRP`. Compare the value with 'u' (`v[.GRP] < u`). Get the index for the first `TRUE` (`which.max`):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(q)[ , which.max(v[.GRP] < u), by = w]
#    w V1
# 1: a  3
# 2: b  4
# 3: c  2
```